# Reference to other entity property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two models in the database in a C# project looking like this:

```
public Company 
{
   {other props... }
   public string Account{ get; set; }
   // This is the prop I want from the Account with Account.Account == Company.Account
   public int BudgetEntryType { get; set; }
}
```

```
public Account
{
   public string Account{ get; set; }
   public int BudgetEntryType { get; set; }
}
```

The value of Company.BudgetEntryType is defined in Account.BudgetEntryType, and is dependent on the value of Company.BudgetEntryType.

Is there a way of doing so? So the Company.BudgetEntryType is a reference to the Account.BudgetEntryType.

Comment: You have to assign an "Account" to a "Company" and then querying it for the "BudgetEntryType".

Comment: The first thing is that if the property is in two classes and they are inter dependent then, it is a redundant data, anyway if you want to fill it, only way is to fill it with query.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BudgetEntryType { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    //other code  

}
```

//-----using

```
        Company company = new Company { Name = "Samsung" };
        db.Companies.Add(company);

        Account account = new Account { Company = company, BudgetEntryType = 2 };
        db.Accounts.Add(account);            
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65392233/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The Line can be delete:  public List<Account> accounts { get; set; } ; Class Account is important for reference.

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question. Please explain.

Comment: For EF Core to bind models, the model Account must have a property: CompanyId, Company. The easiest way.

Comment: Then how does `Company` know `Account`'s `BudgetEntryType`?

Comment: Company samsung = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Samsung");
            var accounts = db.Accounts.Where(a => a.Company == samsung);
            foreach (var account in accounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(account.BudgetEntryType);
            }

Comment: First of all, here need to think about creating models depending on the tasks.

Comment: I showed you how EF can help. Is it logical?